# Python make systems

Tags: python, makefile

What are the benefits and problems with the various Python `make`-like systems?

**note** We're using the denotations '**(+)**' and '**(-)**' respectively at the beginning of list items to indicate benefits and problems.

So far I'm aware of

- [buildit](http://agendaless.com/Members/chrism/software/buildit/)

  - was previously known as `pymake`
  - **(-)** seems to be obsolescing: last release was in late 2007
- [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.5.0b2)

  - **(+)** currently active as of 2010-07-20
  - uses rc-file-like syntax with `[sections]`
  - **(-)** python code cannot (?) readily be integrated into config files.
  - seems to place a lot of emphasis on working with `.egg` files.
- [scons](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SCons/0.92)

  - **(+)** currently active as of 2010-07-20
  - configuration files are written in pure Python
  - **(+)** python code can readily be integrated into config files
  - **(-)?** use of Python for config files may entail extra verbosity
- [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf)

  - **(+)?** [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151019) says "Benefits as `scons` but faster"
  - Any downsides?  Why are people still using `scons`?

Comment: "extra verbosity"?  It sure seems clearer and more precise than any alternative.  What's the point of this question?

Comment: perhaps as a repository for information about python `make` tools (at least that's my presumption considering the CW status)

Comment: I just did a quick bit of research into the options out there, and came up with this list.  I'm wondering a) if there are more options and b) if there are some other notable aspects to the options listed here.

Comment: @S.Lott: You're saying you prefer the file format used by `scons` out of the options listed?  What is imprecise or unclear about the file formats used by `buildit` or `zc.buildout`?  From what I gather, those packages have file formats more specifically tailored to their task; as such I would expect them to be more concise, but less powerful, than `scons`' full-on Python format.

Comment: @intuited: "I would expect".  Sounds like a value judgment, not a question or a fact.

Comment: @S.Lott: It's a guess, thus the **?** for that bullet.  Presumably they chose to use a custom format rather than pure Python; my guess as to the rationale for this decision is that they wanted to create a more concise format.  Of course it could be that this was due to other factors, e.g. preventing/diagnosing dangerous errors.    ................  I posted this question because I wanted to learn more about this topic from those already knowledgeable, rather than taking the time to perform a detailed analysis of all the various options.  If you have more information, please add it to the wiki.

Comment: @S.Lott: Um... maybe you have a problem with your web proxy server or something..  the first line of the question is "What are the benefits and problems with the various Python make-like systems?"  Basically I'm looking for reasons to choose or avoid each of the many available options.  By "dangerous errors" I'm referring to the possibility of causing unforeseen problems by making mistakes when writing a "configuration file" that will actually be evaluated as Python code.  This an example of something that I'd like to know about where it is a possibility.

Comment: @intiuted: "the first line of the ..." Apologies.  The problem is at the edge of too long and hard to follow.  Clearly, I could not follow it, since it was too complex and non-specific.

Comment: @intuited: "the possibility of causing unforeseen problems by making mistakes when writing a "configuration file" that will actually be evaluated as Python code."  What about unforeseen problems by making mistakes when writing a "configuration file" that is in some home-brewed language that is insecure, full of bugs, and can't be compiled properly by the tool?  Why is "python" as a configuration language "dangerous"?  A python-based build tool is distributed as source.  One can more easily just edit the tool itself to be dangerous.

Comment: @S.Lott: It's a good point: An unreliable and buggy configuration file parser should definitely be noted with a **(-)**. A well-implemented configuration language is safer for the same reason that a gun with a safety is safer: you're less likely to shoot yourself in the foot with it. ¶ Python, as general-purpose programming languages go, is eminently suited to being used for configuration purposes, but it's nonetheless often preferable to use a language more specific to the problem domain. If `scons`'s config format is evolved to the point of being a DSL, that would definitely be a **(+)**.

Comment: You may want to add framework-related build tools such as django's manage.py.  It's also easily extensible.

Comment: @intuited: So, Python as a configuration language is still a - even though there's no actual problem?

Comment: @S.Lott: There's no confirmed problem, just inference based on its mode of operation.  That's why there's a question mark.  Remember, it's a list of pros and cons, not of beatification and damnation.  On the other hand, you seem to know a fair bit about `scons` and support its use.. can you provide some details to show that it's free of the typical problems that are associated with using a general-purpose language as a configuration file format, whose inevitability has led to the establishment of various markup formats intended largely for use in configuration files?

Comment: @intuited: "typical problems that are associated with using a general-purpose language as a configuration"  Doesn't mean anything.  There are no problems.  As you said "general-purpose programming languages ... eminently suited to being used for configuration purposes".  "inevitability has led to the establishment of various markup formats intended largely for use in configuration files" is historically inaccurate.  DSL's came first.

Comment: @S.Lott: What are you saying that I was saying there?  There's a grammatical glitch in your ellipticism and I can't figure out if you understood my original point.  ||||||  I'm confused about your second point, too: are you saying that DSLs predated general-purpose programming languages?  Or just that they were commonly used for configuration before GP languages were?  If the latter be the case, I humbly submit that this historical curiosity came about due to the unsuitability of GP languages for use in configuration files.

Comment: @S.Lott: There's also some ambiguity in the use of the word "DSL".  As Martin Fowler [discusses](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html), an *external* DSL is the class of entity of which typical rc-style configuration files are an instance (or a cloned & modified prototype...).  An *internal*, or *embedded* DSL, on the other hand, remaps a GP language for a specific task, e.g. Rails.  I find the idea of a make system using an internal DSL built with Python quite appealing, and I'm wondering if `scons`, `waf`, or some other system works this way.

Comment: @intuited: "I can't figure out if you understood my original point"  If your original point is that using Python for a configuration language is "dangerous", then your point has no evidence or substance.  If your point is that  "general-purpose programming languages [are] eminently suited to being used for configuration purposes" Then your point is true.

Comment: @intuited: "historical curiosity came about due to the unsuitability of GP languages"  Would be both biased and false.  Clearly, you're just looking for evidence to make some point.  DSL configuration languages (i.e. Make) came first because they're simpler than using a general purpose language (i.e., C or the shell).  GP languages lacked any suitable declarative capabilities.  It's not a "curiosity".

Comment: @intuited: "DSL built with Python" makes no pragmatic sense.  Python works.  Has no problems.  Is error-free.  Is not "dangerous" (an undefined term).  Why do extra work inventing, parsing, debugging and refining a useless, confusing DSL when Python already works?  Why downvote SCONS because Python already works?

Comment: We seem to have a mutual impedance mismatch that makes a theoretical discussion largely pointless.  Can you please post some details on how the `scons` configuration format works to provide some support for your assertion that vanilla Python is ideally suited for this task?  I mean last I checked, you had to write about 40 extra characters just to run a system command, so there are clearly some perceivable detriments to the idea of using Python as the language for a make system.  How are they dealing with such issues?  How well does it work?  What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: is waf not on pypi? `pip search waf` and pypi search does not show it, made me sad. scons was there though...

Answer (score 4):

One quirk of waf is that it's supposed to be copied into the source tree of the program.  Scons is a lot more like make in that it's installed once on the system, and then you have essentially just a data file (in the form of a python program) in the source tree.

As a consequence, Scons is packaged on Ubuntu/Debian and waf is not.

It's possible but a bit hard in Scons to do metaprogramming that manipulates the dependency graph or adds new concepts for derivation.  Apparently waf is better at that.

I have used Scons happily many times; for my next compiled project I will probably at least try waf.

You can read about [Samba's experience with waf](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Waf).  They report that going from autoconf to Waf got the rpaths set correctly and shrunk the binaries by linking the necessary object files exactly once per program.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the status of 4 of the software build systems for Python 3, as of 2015-05-31.

- **waf**:

  - (+) The latest version is 1.8.10, dated 2015-05-24.
  - (+) Supports Python 2.5 to 3.4.
  - https://waf.io/book/
- **zc.buildout**:

  - (+) Latest release: 2.3.1, dated 2014-12-16
  - (+) Supports Python 2.6 to 3.4.
  - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout
- **scons**:

  - (-) As of 2014-09-27, *scons* has stalled in its port to Python 3, due to *scons* being a volunteer-run effort.
  - http://www.scons.org/RELEASE.txt
- **buildit**:

  - (-) Does not support Python 3.
  - (-) as of 2013-11-17, version 0.81 is the latest.
  - Development Status :: 3 - Alpha
  - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/buildit/

Answer (score -1):

When I used waf about 1.5-2 years ago, it had really sparse and poor documentation which greatly limited its utility. I haven't used waf in a while, though, so maybe that situation has changed.

Comment: Should be a comment, it certainly isn't an answer.